# Reading bytes from MySQL BLOB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, blob, php-7

I'm trying to read a BLOB field to integer array

(I would like to use a byte, but there is no `byte` data type in PHP, right?)

This is how I read my data with one blob field:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = mysqlConnect();
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM vectors LIMIT 2;");

    echo "\r";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    { 
        $date                  = $row["date"];   // DATETIME
        $vector                = $row["vector"]; // BLOB

        echo $date . "\t";

        $data = unpack("H*", $vector)[1];

        var_dump($data);
        echo "\n";
    }
?>
```

This is a product of my code:

```
2017-12-01  string(6226) "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"

2017-12-01  string(10538) "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"
```

And this is what I need:

```
2017-12-01  array(3113) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(24) [2]=> int(41) ... }

2017-12-01  array(5269) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(15) [2]=> int(32) ... }
```

I probably could split string that comes from `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and convert hex values to integer byte by byte, but I need efficient way to do this beacause there is a lot of data to process and server is very busy.

Questions:

1. Can I read BLOB with mysqli as array of numbers **without wasting memory on strings**?
2. If not - how can I get my bytes in a efficient way?

I'm using PHP7, but I can use older version if necessary.

Comment: How did you store data into that blob in the first place? Use the reverse approach. Is that an array of numbers encoded using some custom scheme stored there?

Comment: @N.B. I can't change my BLOB structure. It has most efficient as possible. It contains raw 11-byte data samples, saved one by one. Im using first 3 bytes to store time of day (hour, minute, second) and 8 bytes for 64-bit value of sample. I'm using database blob like this to avoid huge index and huge record count in a table with measurements. It's like 3-rd dimension of my table.

Comment: But you *saved* that data *somehow*. Now you want to convert that data in its original form and you're asking other people to do that. So, without knowing how it's stored (you just wrote how it's stored) then it's really difficult to tell you how to convert it back. I'd argue you went with the wrong approach, you can't even use that data in MySQL, you're basically using the database as glorified `.bin` file. Anyway, it looks like you're after `hex2bin` function. Will it be of use - no clue, but it fits your requirement, you'll get binary representation of that hex code.

Comment: @N.B. Data comes from C# application, where I could just create byte array, fill it and put it into a database using .NET MySQL Connector library. Later I want to insert data in C++ for better efficiency.

Comment: Storing `json` sounds much better because you can manipulate `json` in MySQL directly, query it etc. I've no clue what you're using this for, but if you can't use your database to query and transform data, then you're in trouble (just like you are now). What are you optimizing anyway? Space used to store data? Using a construct of one language doesn't mean you can use the data in the same way in another language. Try to `hex2bin` after unpacking, see if that's what you want.

Comment: @N.B. My data is too big for JSON stuff. System must be ready to consume about 1.000.000 data samples per day on tiny cloud with few single CPU servers :) Using PHP for this is probably bad idea too, but I have no choice for now.

Comment: Granted - I don't know what you're doing. I've got a few busy projects that process several millions of records per day on rather small vpcs. I understand that you probably can't change what you did, but it's clear that storing the data in a better way would let you manipulate it from the database, since that's database's job. Good luck with this, it sounds like a nightmare :)